# Is it possible to reuse a SELECT expression into a RETURNING expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given something like:

```
SELECT 
    a,
    b,
    fn(c),
    fn2(a, d),
    d
FROM table_name
...
```

is it possible to factor those fields away into something that can be reused in a `RETURNING` statement like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES ...
RETURNING <here>
```

?

#### What have I tried

I know that the SELECT statement could be factored out into a view, but it doesn't seem like I can reuse that view in the `RETURNING`.

Inserting into a view is theoretically possible in certain cases but it seems impossible if you have `fn` and `fn2`.

#### Actual use case

I'm working with Dapper on .NET Core and I'm trying to return a specific subset of fields from the table to return to always the same object.

I could create a separate function in C# that would make a `SELECT` with those specific fields and reuse that function instead, but I'm just wondering if this would be possible just using SQL.

Comment: No, it is not possible.  The `returning` statement relates to the rows inserted by `insert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
with i as (
      INSERT INTO table_name
          VALUES ...
          RETURNING *
     )
SELECT a, b, fn(c), fn2(a, d), d
FROM table_name;
```

That is, you don't have to use the results from the CTE in the `SELECT`.  This seems really weird.  Why not just execute two separate statements?

Or, perhaps you intend this:

```
with i as (
      INSERT INTO table_name
          VALUES ...
          RETURNING *
     )
SELECT a, b, fn(c), fn2(a, d), d
FROM i;
```

Comment: Just curiosity. Wouldn't two statements (even if the second is a `SELECT` probably by the `PRIMARY KEY` which, as far as I know, is indexed) be less performant than using a `RETURNING` statement for all fields? Again, just curiosity, I know the performance difference would be extremely little. :)

Comment: Also I don't see how you factored the fields out so that it can be used both in a `SELECT` and a `RETURNING`. It seems like you would need to list those fields out anyway. What am I missing?

Comment: @Shoe . . . I don't see what a primary key has to do with it.  You are returning all the rows from `i`.  I can't say whether executing the functions during the insert would be faster or slower, because inserts are doing a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean

```
create function fn (param integer) returns integer
language sql as
    'select 1000 * param;';

create table a (
    id serial not null,
    data character varying(256) not null
);

insert into a (data)
select 'test'
returning id, fn(id);
```